# Python regex, how to find number between two floats

Tags: python, regex, floating-point, range

I am trying to find the values between 40.00 and 99.00 in a list, but i am having trouble including both floats in the code.

```
 r'([4-9][0-9]|\d{3,})\.'
```

yields me the numbers greater than 40, but I cannot figure out how to also add the less than 99.00 part.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure regex is the best tool for this job? Either way,  provide some inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Not to be that person, but did you consider parsing the strings into numbers and comparing against those instead?

Comment: Regex is not the only way to solve this problem. I believe list comprehension would be easier and more efficient. `result = [i for i in first_list if i in range(44, 99)]`

Comment: It is not clear, you say you want numbers between 34 and 99 but your regex contains `\d{3,}` that matches any 3 or more digit number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
\b[4-8]\d\.\d+|90\.\d+\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dxdniq/1/) but as stated in the comments section, you might be better off using a list comprehension with `range(...)` instead, though.

Answer (score -1):

The following regular expressions works for your problem:

```
^[4-9][0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

[image]

Regular expressions are, oftentimes, hard to read. It's likely better to write this:

```
for item in items:
    if item >= 40.00 and item <= 99.00:
        # logic
```

Comment: First suggestion - ok. Second suggestion - won't work since A) the list probably contains strings. B) `range` does not work with floats. `2.1 in range (1, 100)` is `False`. Also, `range(40, 99)` "contains" 40 - 98.